# Can a geometric interpretation be given for the Cartesian product of a triangle and a line segment?

Tags: coordinate-systems

The question is asked in a textbook. I tried to answer the question by assuming A={(2,2),(1,1),(3,1)} B={(1,1),(3,3)} So when I did Cartesian product AXB, I got {(2,1),(1,1,(3,3),(3,1),(1,3),(3,2),(2,3),(1,2),(2,2)} which translated to a Square. Am I correct? Will that hold true for all the Cartesian products of a triangle and a  line segment? How to prove in general?   [image: Representation of A and B in Cartesian plane]

[image: Cartesian product]

Comment: That is not at all what the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) is. If both your triangle and your line segment are subsets of the plane, then their Cartesian product would live in 4-dimensional space.

Comment: What is the answer for , ‘Can you give a geometric interpretation for the Cartesian product of a triangle and a line segment?’

Comment: For me, the answer is "yes, I can". For you the answer is currently "no, I cannot". But we should work on changing that answer by my pointing you in the right direction, and you actually putting some thought into exploring that direction instead of just demanding I give you an answer you will not internalize, thus not actually changing the correct answer for you to this question. So far, I've pointed out that whatever you thought you were doing (I can't figure that out myself), it is not the Cartesian product, and I've pointed you to what the Cartesian product actually is.

Comment: The actual cartesian product of your sets $A, B$ would be $$A\times B = \{((2,2),(1,1)), ((1,1),(1,1)), ((3,1),(1,1)),\\ ((2,2),(3,3)), ((1,1),(3,3)), ((3,1),(3,3))\}$$You can identify the pairs-within-pairs of this set with 4-tuples. So you could also think of it as $$\{(2,2,1,1),(1,1,1,1),(3,1,1,1),(2,2,3,3),(1,1,3,3),(3,1,3,3)\}$$which are points in $\Bbb R^4$, 4-dimensional space.

Comment: One other thing you need to think about. Even though it lies in a plane, a line segment is itself just a 1-dimensional object. The cross-product of a 1-dimensional object and a 2-dimensional object is going to be 3-dimensional. So while your cross-product lies in 4-dimensional space, one of those dimensions is not necessary. It is like looking at a triangle in space, as compared to in a plane. So what 3-dimensional object do you get from crossing a triangle with a line segment?

Comment: No, I am not demanding an answer. I am trying to understand it. But unable to do so. I explored online resources, but unable to get the answer. So, I ventured with my own interpretation of all the set of ordered pairs that could come from the Cartesian product of a triangle and a line segment. I was able to understand the point you were making. The question I was asking is similar to the point, geometric interpretation of a line segment and a circle could be considered as the lateral surface of a right circular cylinder. Both my question and the last example are from,‘Methods of Real Analysis’

Comment: Your first comment was a demand for an answer. That may not be how you were thinking of it, but it is what it amounts to. My reply was to explain why I will not simply give you an answer. I'm sorry that the limited space and time available prevent me from being more diplomatic about it. I want you to realize for yourself what is going on, not just have a memorized answer you still don't understand. You know that the product of a line with a circle gives a cylinder? What happens when you replace the circle with a triangle?

Comment: Is it lateral surface of a cone?

Comment: Cones are circular. Where in a line segment and a triangle do you see anything that suggests circularity? How about trying this. Let $B$ be the particular line segment $B = \{(t, 0) \mid 0 \le t \le 1\}$. You can use the $A$ you already have, but remember that you actually want a *triangle*, not just its three vertices. Use the correct cross-product as I've demonstrated. Note that all of the points will have last coordinate $0$, since $B$ does. So you can ignore that coordinate and look at the other 3 as a point in 3D space. What shape do you get?

Comment: I got something like a prism?

Comment: Yes. It is a prism. Do you see why? Just like crossing the circle with the line segment gives you a cylinder - a surface that in one direction goes around a circle, and the perpendicular direction goes in a straight line - crossing the triangle with the line segment gives you a surface that in one direction goes around a triangle, and the perpendicular direction goes in a straight line.

Comment: Thank you! I will accept yours as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulSinclair it happens to be a triangular prism; line segment is one dimensional and a triangle is two dimensional, when Cartesian product(all possible ordered pairs) is taken, it results in a three dimensional triangular prism